# CURL is Giving different results on two different servers

Tags: php, curl, centos

This is a pretty simple example of using a CURL in my php script to test two servers results.  All of a sudden my code broke and I have no idea what happened.  Here is the scenario we have two or i thought so identical servers setup with WHM/Cpanel and two identical sets of cloned git repositories.  One is our staging server the other our production box.

My problem is that one server staging returns the expected results for the simple scripts below.  Our production box just returns nulls.  I checked the configuration on both servers with phpinfo() and curl is installed correctly.

My question is has anyone out there had this problem before.  I would really like to figure this out and it will probably fix the program we so desperately need.

Thanks again for any responses.  Note the code below is only to show CURL working not validating any responses or error's that may have occurred; however, we will display any if they are present.

We tested the same code on two servers stagingpinnaclemedplus.com works, pmpcustomer.com returns null values.

```
// pageCurl.php

 $data['key'] = $_POST['key'];
 $data['pdf'] = $_POST['pdf'];
 $data['session_id']= $_POST['session_id'];

 echo json_encode($data);
```

```
// pagetestcurl.php

       session_start();
       $url = 'http://stagingpinnaclemedplus.com/pageCurl.php';

        $postData['key']= 'LABEL_PATH';
        $postData['pdf'] = 'off';       // Signifies for the PHP page to create PDF file not shown to browser
        $postData['print_mode'] = 'c';
        $postData['session_id'] = session_id();


            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array(
                $ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
            ));
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            $error = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
echo "</br>";
echo "Result:".print_r($result).'</br>';
if($error)
echo "Error:".var_dump($error);
```

When i run the code on the staging server we get what i expect:

```
{"key":"LABEL_PATH","pdf":"off","session_id":"r2jkkmbhd73maj9e8o72mdvqq3"} Result:1\
```

When i run it on my production box (note the url host name is changed to pmpcustomer.com) for testpagecurl.php.  I get this result:

```
[Result: {"key":null,"pdf":null,"session_id":null} 
string(0) "" Error:]
```

Comment: Are the keys set on `$_POST`? Or the entire variable is null?

Comment: The $dataPost array is passing suppose to pass the values to the pageCurl.php, my expectation is to just read the values from the $_POST request and simply display those values through the calling pagetestcurl.php.  what i am seeing is that curl is not passing the values at all to, hence our null values.